# scala gson array elements to scala ArrayList[Int]

Tags: scala, gson, scala-java-interop

I'm facing problem converting back and forth between java, gson, scala. How should i do that.

How should i do in functional way my objective is to collect all the array elements for jsonArray and populate it to the ArrayClass array.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import java.util.ArrayList

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

class ArrayClass {
  var array = new ArrayList[Int]
}

class ArrayClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer[ArrayClass] {

  def deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): ArrayClass = {
    val jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject
    val jsonArray = jsonObject.get("array").getAsJsonArray
    val arrayClass = new ArrayClass
    val arraylist = new ArrayList[JsonElement]()
    **jsonArray.iterator().foreach(e => arrayClass.array.add(e.getAsInt))**
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need for vague construction with `ArrayClass` and nested field `array` you can make direct transformation with converted type and `map` function:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val javaList = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()
val result = javaList.iterator.toList.map(_.getAsInt)
```

If you don't need for `ArrayList` as temporary result holder, just cast it to the correct type:

```
 val ints = javaList.iterator
                      .asInstanceOf[java.util.Iterator[Int]]
                      .toList.map(_.getAsInt)
```

If you don't want to deal with Scala's collections just make an iterator which returns `getAsInt` and convert it to `ArrayList` via `Guava`:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

Iterator<Integer> ints = ....
List<Integer> myList = Lists.newArrayList(ints);
```

or same with ArrayClass

```
Iterator<ArrayClass> ints = ....
List<Integer> myList = Lists.newArrayList(ints).stream.map(p -> p.getAsInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In result, you will obtain List of Integers, the choice is yours.